# How to download a configuration file to the root of the project automatically?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a lot of java maven projects with `lombok.config`, `.editorconfig` files in the root of every project. All those files are the same for all projects.

A problem appears when I need to update one of those files. It's not very often but when I need it it's quite painful to copy/paste the changes to 50 projects, push all changes to master, etc.

The idea is to move those files to a new git repository and when I run `mvn install` at one of my projects some plugin should go to that repository and update file in the root of the project if necessary. Does somebody know if such plugin exist? Any other ideas for resolving the problem are also appreciated.

Comment: `.editorconfig` is for your IDE, I assume, while `lombok.config` will be part of the final product?

Comment: yes, I need to duplicate it to the root of all projects along with `.editorconfig`: all team has the same editor configurations

Comment: For those elements that will end up in the product, you can define a parent Maven pom.xml. But as these files will be loaded only during the Maven runs, this does not work for the IDE files. Perhaps you can modify the project creation for your IDE that it will pull its configuration files from a centralised location? Although this will only affect new projects …